# SWT file drop: identify folders

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

**Code**

I'm trying to add drop functionality to my program so users can drag and drop files from Windows. Therefore I implemented the SWT [`DropTargetListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fdnd%2FDropTargetListener.html) interface and added a SWT [`DropTarget`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/dnd/DropTarget.html) to my SWT control.

```
public class MyFileDrop implements DropTargetListener {

public MyFileDrop(final Control control) {
    addDropTarget(control);
}

private void addDropTarget(final Control control) {
    final DropTarget dropTarget = new DropTarget(control, DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_DEFAULT);
    dropTarget.setTransfer(new Transfer[] { FileTransfer.getInstance() });
    dropTarget.addDropListener(this);
}

@Override
public void drop(final DropTargetEvent event) {
    String[] fileNames = (String[]) event.data;
    for (final String fileName : fileNames) {
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}

// other DropTargetListener methods [...]
}
```

If I drag and drop a folder from Windows Explorer to my control, the folder name gets printed out. But all files inside that dropped folder aren't listed.

**Example**

> folder1
>    - subfile1.png
>    - subfile2.exe
>   file1.png
>   file2.exe

If I select `folder1`, `file1` and `file2` and drag and drop it to my program, this is the output:

```
path/to/folder1
path/to/file1.png
path/to/file2.exe
```

**Questions**

1. Why aren't the files inside the folder dropped to the program? How can I archive that these files are also dropped?
2. How can I set the files apart from the folder?

Regards winklerrr

Comment: These seems to be about the behavior of Windows Explorer which is outside the control of the SWT code. The drop target just gets what the source wants to give it.

Comment: You dragged three items, a folder and two files. That's what you see in your code. If you want to get files recursively, you'll have to do that yourself. You can distinguish between files and folders by using `Files#isDirectory(Path)`  and `Files#isRegularFile(Path)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

So this is my solution

```
@Override
public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
    String[] fileNames = (String[]) event.data;
    for (String fileName : fileNames) {
        final File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            Collection<File> subFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(file, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
            for (File subFile : subFiles) {
                System.out.println(subFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

I used the [`FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from the [`commons-io`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) package.

**Example**

> folder1
>    - subfile1.png
>    - subfile2.exe
>   file1.png
>   file2.exe

With the new code, this is now the output:

```
path/to/folder1/subfile1.png
path/to/folder1/subfile2.exe
path/to/file1.png
path/to/file2.exe
```

**Answers**

*How can I archive that these files are also dropped?*
[`FileUtils.listFiles(File, IOFileFilter, IOFileFilter)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter))

*How can I set the files apart from the folder?*
[`File.isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory())

Comment: [`File#listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) would have done it as well without a library.